# Can Windows OS be installed and run as read-only?

Tags: windows, security, read-only

I have a DoD CentOS install on a CD, so even if the code in RAM is infected, a reboot eliminates the malware.  But I am not a UNIX guy and would prefer to work with Windows.

I had an old vs of Windows on a CD that did the trick (but lost it).  Is there a variant of Windows that I could install and then make read-only?  I assume the swap file would need to be on a read-write drive.

Comment: If the only problem were the pagefile, you could just turn paging off (and add real RAM instead). See how long your windows survives when you take aways write access to %windir% from all (including SYSTEM). You'd have to take special casre for registry hives, event logs, ...

Comment: By say read only what do you mean ? To not let anyone install anything, to not allow any program to write on disk ?, to not allow changes to the system by installing programs ?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft offered a program called [Windows SteadyState](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState). SteadyState was discontinued, but they did publish a [TechNet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg176676%28WS.10%29.aspx) on how to implement some of the same features.

There are also commercial applications, such as Deep Freeze.

You could also run Windows in a virtual machine, and use snapshots to roll back to a known good state.

Comment: For Vista an later using a virtual install and rolling that back to startup time when you want to start whit a clean state is the easiest approach. Alternatively you can use a real machine with a product like Acronis TrueImage. Takes about 10 minutes on a modern machine to restore a full Win7 back to the startup state.. That's probably faster than trying to boot a Windows "LiveCD".

Comment: Windows Embedded supports read only using a File-Based Write Filter for similar functionality. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794219%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx